# string formatting on view or controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Novice on this 'asp.net mvc' but familiar with mvp pattern for mobile app(mvc#).

Required business logic is to display 'firmware version' in a format like "1.03".

I found it can be formatted either in Controller:

```
ViewBag.deviceFirmwareVersion = String.Format("{0}.{1}", result.VERSION_MAJOR[0], result.VERSION_MINOR[0]);
```

or in View:

```
<td>@String.Format("{0}.{1}", Model.VERSION_MAJOR[0], Model.VERSION_MINOR[0])</td>
```

Then, what is the difference? Of course I preferred doing it in a Controller. Mvc# makes view as simple as possible (dumm view) and let it depends on presenter about what to do. Is there a simliar rule here?

[02 Nov 12] Maybe my question was a bit off focused, I ended up creating view model where I pick up necessary pieces from data entity and formatting them for view. [This link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2010/01/26/view-models-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx) helped me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With MVC paradigm, all the things about *showing* informations has to be described in the View, because informations can be get in differents formats (HTML, JSON, XML) and if you format the data in controller then you have to check for every type of format you may show.
If you use only HTML can be easy *now* to set data format in the controller, but further can get you in trouble.

(Sorry for bad English)